# Symfony 2.7 Translating Constraint Messages not supporting locale

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I just updated my Symfony from 2.5 to 2.7. I have an Entity, in this case `Product` that has a some properties with some constraints, for example `year`.

```
    class Product {

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true, options={"default" = 0.00})
         * @Assert\NotBlank( message = "product.year.notBlank")
         */
        private $year;
    }
```

My message is getting translated from the `app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml` file. But now, it doesn't respect the locale anymore. I have 2 files the `en` version and the `fr` version but now it only gets the `en` version.

It works fine for any labels that I have in my forms, the problem is specific to the validators files.

Comment: you have a validators.fr.yml file, right?

Comment: I have a app/Resources/translations/validators.fr.yml file and I have cleared my cache on many occasions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working now. The problem was that I was calling this listener

```
projet_user.language.kernel_request_listener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser }
```

and now I moved the content of the `setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser` function in the `onKernelRequest` function of the listerner.

```
projet_user.locale_listener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

It seems like the request that I was using for unauthenticated users is now called later and was impacting the locale defined by the users preferences. I'm gonna do some more tests and close the ticket.